# Trouble reading a HTML file like a JSON via AJAX without getting 'unexpected token' error

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

I have a Siemens s7 1200 PLC with a webpage on it that is formatted like a json file (except it is html, but it needs to be html so the PLC can change variables on it).
I am trying to read the contents of that from a external webserver by using an ajax request. I can only succesfully get data when using `'dataType': "jsonp"` because that way i get around the cross domain issue but when doing the ajax request it gives an error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: unexpected token: ':'                          api.htm:2:9

which is in the file I'm reading with the ajax request.
The error is probably because it is expecting a json file, but it is getting a html file.

How do i get around this?

​

this is the api.htm file:

```
{
    "Muntje"::="Feedback-WS".Muntje:,
    "AdK"::="Feedback-WS".Aanraking_der_Kunst:,
    "Juwelenkistje"::="Feedback-WS".Juwelenkistje:,
    "Duivelsbeeld"::="Feedback-WS".Duivelsbeeld:,
    "Klok"::="Feedback-WS".Klok:,
    "Hertenpoot"::="Feedback-WS".Hertenpoot:,
    "Zekering_Kledingkast"::="Feedback-WS".Zekering_Kledingkast:,
    "Bed_knop_1"::="Feedback-WS".Bed_knop_1:,
    "Bed_knop_2"::="Feedback-WS".Bed_knop_2:,
    "Bed_knop_3"::="Feedback-WS".Bed_knop_3:,
    "Bed_knop_4"::="Feedback-WS".Bed_knop_4:,
    "Vacuum_Pomp"::="Feedback-WS".Vacuum_Pomp:,
    "Signaal_Generator"::="Feedback-WS".Signaal_Generator:,
    "Stekkerrek"::="Feedback-WS".Stekkerrek:,
    "Zekering_1"::="Feedback-WS".Zekering_1:,
    "Zekering_2"::="Feedback-WS".Zekering_2:,
    "Zekering_3"::="Feedback-WS".Zekering_3:,
    "Hoofdschakelaar"::="Feedback-WS".Hoofdschakelaar:,
    "Morse_Code"::="Feedback-WS".Morse_Code:
}
```

and this is the code that is trying to read the api.htm page.

```
var settings = {
                'cache': false,
                'dataType': "jsonp",
                "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                "async": true,
                "crossDomain": true,
                "url": "http://192.168.22.160/awp/TIR/api.htm",
                "method": "GET",
                "headers": {
                    "accept": "application/json",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*"
                }
            }
            
            $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
                //console.log($.parseJSON(response));
                
            });
```

Comment: Why do you have a file that's neither HTML nor JSON?

Comment: the 'api.htm' file needs the have the .htm or .html extension so that the PLC which that file is on can change the variables (such as :="Feedback-WS".Muntje:)
but the contents need to be formatted like a json

Comment: "Like JSON" and "is valid JSON" are very different things. The content in the htm is not valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding `let jsonString = '` in front of the JSON data (and of course closing it with another `')` so that JavaScript doesn't throw any errors and I have my JSON data in a string.
Probably not the way it should be done, but it works.

Comment: The data will then be invalid JS instead of invalid JSON.